# Application Terminates due to Popover

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am working on IPad application. As per requirement On detail page of SplitviewController I am adding one customized UIBarButtonItem leftbar button on navigation bar.

Now in Portrait mode when I click this button I am getting following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Popovers cannot be presented from a
>   UIBarButtonItem that is not in a
>   toolbar or navigation bar already.'

Can one please help on this ????

Thanks,

Sagar

Comment: You should post the code that the button calls to present the popover.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely didn't declare your UIButtonItem variable correctly. Make sure it matches everywhere throughout your code.

For more info check out my [blog post](http://bencoffman.com/blog/2011/02/14/TerminatingAppDueToUncaughtExceptionNSInvalidArgumentExceptionReasonPopoversCannotBePresentedFromA.aspx).